# store Prolog answers to a file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, writefile, file-storage

I'm working with ALEPH reasoning engine in SWI-Prolog. I want to save the rules that ALEPH infers and shows them in SWI-Prolog console, but I have no idea how can I do it!
The sample result is depicted in the picture below,

```
[Rule 134] [Pos cover = 1 Neg cover = 0]
likes(u9,soccer).
[Rule 135] [Pos cover = 3 Neg cover = 0]
friends(A,u2) :- age(A,adult).
[Rule 136] [Pos cover = 2 Neg cover = 0]
friends(A,u5) :- age(A,adult).
[Rule 137] [Pos cover = 1 Neg cover = 0]
trusts(u1,u5).
[Rule 138] [Pos cover = 1 Neg cover = 0]
trusts(u5,u7).
```

these rules are shown after calling the induction procedure with this commands:
    - read_all(aleph_files).
    - induce.

Now I'm wondering how I can store these rules into a txt file automatically.

Comment: @false see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/aleph/info

Comment: @muhuk: You are right! Thank you. I rolledback my rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It is only needed to say:

```
write_rules(FileName).
```